# When trying to add Tab in sales I get this error

Tags: magento2, layout, adminhtml, sales-order, uicomponent

This is my Ui component code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="custom_field" class="Sales\WalletDeatils\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Wallet Used</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

But I'm getting is below error.

```
The requested component ("filter") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.
```

I can't trigger what is the error.